# Remove table-hover effect for a single cell in a Twitter Bootstrap table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a web app using Twitter Bootstrap. In one of our views, there is a table that uses the `.table-hover` class. There are some specific cells in the table that I don't want to highlight when the rest of their rows highlight, though. What style rules should I use to achieve this effect?

This is roughly how my view table is organized:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th />
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Row Group "Heading" 1</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Row Group "Heading" 2</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make the cells that span 2 rows not highlight when they are hovered over.

EDIT:

I tried this CSS:

```
td.rowTitle:hover { background-color: transparent; }
```

It doesn't work, unfortunately. I think it may be because the whole row is being highlighted, not just the cell...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what the bootstrap CSS looks like:

```
.table-hover { 
             tbody { tr:hover td, tr:hover th 
                             { background-color: @tableBackgroundHover; } 
                        }
           }
```

With a bit of JQuery:

```
  $('td[rowspan]').addClass('hasRowSpan');
```

You can then use the following CSS to override it:

```
tbody tr:hover td.hasRowSpan { 
          background-color: none;   /* or whatever color you want */
}
```

Comment: it is equivalent to `tbody tr:hover td[rowspan]` and jQuery is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what method is used to create those "hovers", however you can add specific rules for hover if you seperate those cells. So give those cells a class name and you can then set your specific styles/hovers for them.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the element that you don't want the hover e.g.:

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2" class="no-hover">Row Group "Heading" 2</td>
  <td>Content</td>
  <td>Content</td>
  <td>Content</td>
</tr>
```

In your CSS/SCSS:

```
.table-hover {
  .no-hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
}
```

Working in Bootstrap 4.